# Can't send HTTP/HTTPS traffic to a GKE node

Tags: kubernetes, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I get the error below every time I try to open http/https ports on a gke vm so I could let traffic through to my nginx ingress. The Node in kubernetes just dies every time I try to do any changes to firewall configs for the node.

Editing VM instance gke-*-cluster-pool-1-75f2f99f-r3b0 failed. Error: Invalid value for field 'resource.natIP': '104...254'. The specified external IP address '104...254' was not found in region 'europe-west1'.

I have also tried to use the GCE loadbalancer ingress without success, it just gives me another error, which seems to say that it can't bootstrap itself

Error: Server Error

The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get around the crashing of nodes while using the web UI with help of gcloud cli by adding the http tags manually.

```
gcloud compute instances add-tags [YOUR_INSTANCE_NAME] --tags http-server,https-server
```